# Why would delayed_job's handle_asynchronously method push to the model's collection rather than delayed_backend_mongoid_jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, delayed-job

Trying to get delayed_job working with a mongoid backend. The created job fails to run, apparently because it is being pushed to the `db.entries` collection, rather than the `db.delayed_backend_mongoid_jobs` collection.

Given the following code in the class Entry:

```
after_create :create_dj
def create_dj
  Rails.logger.info "ENTRY CREATED at #{created_at}"
end
handle_asynchronously :create_dj, run_at: Proc.new { 30.seconds.from_now }
```

I would expect a new delayed_job entry would be created in the delayed_backend_mongoid_jobs collection. Instead, I see the following db log:

```
MONGODB health_blog_development['entries'].insert([
  {"content"=>"foo", "_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4ee95ed3b643988551000044') ... }, 
  {"priority"=>0, "attempts"=>0, "handler"=>"--- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMethod ... }])
```

as if it thinks it should be pushing the job to the entries collection.

Some details that *might* be relevant:

- Entry has been subclassed. I've tried the code in Entry and its subclass, TextEntry.
- The function runs find when handle_asynchronously is not being used.
- Entry is not an embedded class, but does have several referenced relations.
- I've set config.mongoid.preload_models = true
- I have confirmed that delayed_job works as expected when I use it with a new model in the same project.

Gems used:

- mongoid (2.2.4)
- rails (3.0.9)
- delayed_job (2.1.4)
- delayed_job_mongoid (1.0.4)

Please let me know if there's any other details that might help figure out what's going on here. Cheers!

Comment: I think the issue may in fact be to do with the Apotomo widget views that are processing it.

Comment: Any luck getting this working?

Comment: Yes, changed the process to not use regular Rails forms rather than the Apotomo url_for_event process and it now works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be funny behaviour resulting from the combination of delayed_job and the Apotomo widget framework. Changing the process to use regular Rails forms rather than the Apotomo url_for_event process solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the entries in the delayed_job collection reference the class which creates them, which in this case is the Entry class.

What is the error that you are actually getting?

Comment: There's no error, per se. It just fails to run the job, because it has pushed the job to the `db.entries` collection rather than the `db.delayed_backend_mongoid_jobs` collection. I'll edit the question to clarify that.